# Antonym (sort of) of "intimidating"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that is roughly the opposite of "intimidating", but with negative connotations.  I'm not looking for something like "reassuring," more like "wimpy" or "beneath notice" or "unimportant," perhaps even "tempting others to attempt intimidation," but nothing I've found quite fits the bill.

I'm wanting to say something like, "He was a nice enough guy, she thought, but it was an effort just to take notice of him.  He was ???"

Comment: do you mean someone 'so easy to overlook' ? '  That's a phrase, not a word so I'm not going to submit it unless asked....but that IS something you hear all the time.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes lots of good answers in that previous question thread, if that is the meaning the op is looking for.

Comment: *Unremarkable* might fit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the word [mousy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mousy)? Going off the third definition meaning quiet, shy, or timid. In fact, [timid](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/timid) is a pretty good word for this as well, for one who is fearful and hesitant.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who is [wormy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wormy) is repulsive in a non-threatening way.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that he is [**Feeble**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feeble) or [**Fainthearted**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fainthearted):

> #### Feeble
>
> - Deficient in qualities or resources that indicate vigor, authority, force, or efficiency.

> #### Fainthearted
>
> - Lacking courage or resolution; timid.

Answer (score 1):

From a native speaker and professional writer:

The term you need depends on how harshly you want to express yourself.  In order of harshness and irony: **Sad, invisible, vanilla, wallpaper, dishrag, doormat, nonexistent, pathetic, masochistic**.

Meek, already offered, is very good for a general weakness of nature, without being mean about it.

Invisible fits well in your sentence as it explains why it was hard "to take notice of him."

Comment: "vanilla" and "wallpaper" are very close to what I want, I think.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [**nonthreatening**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonthreatening):

> 1 : not constituting a threat
>
> 2 :  not likely to cause anxiety ; also :  [innocuous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innocuous) 2

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [***insignificant***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/insignificant) correctly expresses the lack of personality?

> (of a person) without power or influence:
>   *‘she was so small and insignificant’*